# Неправильная оценка при поиске fuzziness в elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Помогите пожалуйста с запросом, есть имена и простой запрос по них

```
$request = array(
"from" => 0,
"size"=>1000000,
"query"=> array(
"match"=>array(
"full_description"=>array(
"query"=>$text,
"fuzziness"=> 2,
"prefix_length"=> 1,
)
)
);
```

но когда вбиваеш Иванов оно выдает первым Иванцов, потом Иванов а уже потом все остальное. Почему _score у Иванцова больше чем у Иванова? Пробовал анализаторы, ну код вот такой у меня:
Создание индекса

```
$request = array(
"mappings"=> array(
"person"=>array(
"properties"=>array(
"id"=>array(
"type"=> "integer",
"index"=> "not_analyzed"
),
"updated"=>array(
"type"=> "date",
"index"=> "not_analyzed"
),
"full_description"=>array(
"type"=> "string"
)
)
)
));
```

Выборка из БД плагином jdbc

```
$request = array("type" => "jdbc",
"jdbc"=>array(
"url" => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_m",
"user" => "user",
"password" => "pass",
"sql" => "SELECT id, updated, full_description FROM product_info",
"index"=>"index1",
"type"=>"person"
),
"analysis"=>array(
"analyzer"=> "russian"
)
);
```

Поиск, что закомичено я уже пробовал, ничего не помогает:

```
$request = array(
"from" => 0,
"size"=>1000000,
"query"=> array(
//"match_all"=>array(""=>""),
"match"=>array(
"full_description"=>array(
//"query"=> mb_convert_encoding($text, "utf-8", "CP1251"), //геморой с кодировками, еластик принимает utf-8
"query"=>$text,
"fuzziness"=> 2,
"prefix_length"=> 1,
//"min_similarity"=> "0.5"
)
)/*,
"order"=>array(
"max_score"=> "desc"
)*/
)/*,
"analysis"=>array(
"analyzer"=> "russian"
)*/
/*,
"sort"=>array(
"updated"=>array(
"order"=>"desc",
"ignore_unmapped" => "true"
)
)*/
);
```

Find results:

```
[0] => Array                   (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnYZoelMWbrisONZE
                            [_score] => 1.5704145
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 12713
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванцов Р.Б. 1:1926 2:1960 текст
                                )
                        )
```

.....

```
[507] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnZ1PelMWbrisOVyj
                            [_score] => 0.9315139
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 47112
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Инин Г.П. 1:1991 2:2013 текст
                                )
                        )
```

.....

```
[884] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnaQLelMWbrisOXNm
                            [_score] => 0.7421299
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 52939
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванов М.А. 1:1919 2:1961 текст
                                )
                        )
```

........

```
[8190] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnYFaelMWbrisOLb0
                            [_score] => 0.39577943
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4697
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванова Д.А. 1:1912 2:1954 текст
                                )
                        )
```

.......

```
[8927] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbn2LBelMWbrisQj8R
                            [_score] => 0.3298162
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 629366
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванова-Каменская М.О. 1:1989 2:2003 текст
                                )
                        )
```

Даю запрос с сортировкой и снова какой то бред:

```
$request = array(
            "from" => 0,
            "size"=>1000000,
            "query"=> array(
                "match"=>array(
                        "full_description"=>array(
                                "query"=>$text,
                                "fuzziness"=> 2,
                                "prefix_length"=> 1
                        )
                )
            ),
            "sort"=>array(
                "full_description"=>array(
                    "order"=>"desc",
                    "ignore_unmapped" => "true"
                )
            )
    );

[1] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnYFQelMWbrisOKb6
                            [_score] => 
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 607
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванов Л.А. 1:1918 2:1960 текст
                                )

                            [sort] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => текст
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnYFQelMWbrisOKcB
                            [_score] => 
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 614
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванова-Каменская Л.А. 1:1918 2:1960 текст
                                )

                            [sort] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => текст
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => index1
                            [_type] => person
                            [_id] => AUzbnYFRelMWbrisOKiC
                            [_score] => 
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 999
                                    [updated] => 2015-04-12T00:52:00.000-04:00
                                    [full_description] => Иванов Л.А. 1:1918 2:1960 текст
                                )

                            [sort] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => текст
                                )

                        )
```

Помогите люди добрые, думаю создать мультизапрос, первый по точному значению, а второй з фузинес 2, не будут результаты повторяться?

Comment: На этих конкретных данных у меня проблема не воспроизводится. Иванов идёт первым в результатах. Инин вообще отсутствует. Могу лишь предположить, что это какой-то баг, который уже исправлен в моей версии (у меня 1.5.1).

Comment: Сортировка не работает так просто на `analyzed`-строках. Нужно делать специальный маппинг, чтобы в индексе сохранялась исходная строка, пригодная для сортировки. Гуглить по словам "String Sorting and Multifields".

Comment: А при создании индекса у меня вроде делается mapping, но при поиске ругается то нужно ставить "ignore_unmapped" => "true"

Comment: "ignore_unmapped" - это устаревшая опция... прежде всего нужно обновить версию до последней... не факт, что это поможет, но это нужно сделать в любом случае... elasticsearch не настолько стабилен, чтобы можно было хоть на что-то рассчитывать, имея не самую последнюю версию

Comment: jdbc не раболтает с 1,5,1, у меня стоит 1,5,0. Но попробую поставить 1,5,1

Comment: А можно сделать такой запрос? bool например что бы первым выводились $text, тоисть строго Иванов, потом $text."??" или $text."*", а потому уже с fuzziness 2, что бы без повтором с таким порядком?

Comment: Скорее всего можно. Для этого придётся задать свою функцию ранжирования (вычисления _score). Но это не нужно. Потому что проблема явно не в запросе. У меня такой же запрос работает ожидаемым образом: Иванов первый в результатах.

Comment: Установил самую свежую версию 1.5.2, тоже самое, теперь грешу на jdbc, ща напишу свою загонку БД в индекс и скажу результат.

Comment: И запросы лучше делать напрямую через Sense, а не через PHP.

Comment: Даже не знаю что такое с поиском, ничего сложного в задаче нет, в БД всего 2 поля id и full_description. Маппинг тоже без настроек id=>integer, full_description=>string. Запрос тоже проще простого "fuzziness"=> 2, "prefix_length"=> 1. А воно все равно выдает результаты как хочет. В чем может быть проблемма?

Comment: Если такие же результаты выдаёт запрос, сделанный через Sense, то я даже не представляю, что и где может быть не так. У меня этот же запрос работает через Sense правильно.

Comment: Да разницы нет через Sense или curl php, удалил все кроме имен та же штука, причем порядок не меняется, как первым был Иванцов так и остался. Я думаю это баг потому что Ивановых аж 40 000+ Вот и глючит где то. Когда много результатов то глючит а когда в пределах 1000 то работает норм. Хотя даже когда частями доставать Ивановых все равно та же хрень.

Comment: Надо было сразу сказать, что Ивановых гораздо больше, чем Иванцовых. Если это так, то никакого бага нет. Всё работает ожидаемым образом. Так и должно быть. Распространённость искомых слов среди документов играет важнейшую роль в ранжировании. Чем больше в базе Ивановых, тем менее значимым для ранжировщика будет точное совпадение по слову "Иванов". Гораздо большее значение для него будет иметь тот факт, что "Иванов" может быть Иванцовым, написанным с ошибкой.

Comment: Да, списался с одним человеком и он мне это только что объяснил, как же тогда Иванов вывести на самый верх а все остальное внизу и тоже что бы вместе были а не вперемешку?

Comment: Это две разные проблемы. Первую можно решить через `function_score` запрос. Чтобы вытащить наверх Иванова, нужно задать фильтр на точное совпадение и функцию, которая будет давать огромный _score документам, попадающим в этот фильтр. Решение второй проблемы мне не известно.

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос как? Мне кажется что я делаю глупости
"query"=> array(
    "function_score"=>array(
     "query"=>array(
      "match"=>array(
       "full_description"=>array(
        "query"=>$text,
        "fuzziness"=> 2,
        "prefix_length"=> 1
       )
      )
     ),
     "functions"=>array(
      array(
       "script_score"=> array(
        "script"=> "doc[\"full_description\"].value == ".$text." ? _score*2 : _score"
       )
      )
     ),
     "score_mode"=>"multiply"
    )

Comment: Да, это не будет работать. Во-первых, сам js-скрипт невалиден. Строка, подставленная в него из $text, будет без кавычек. Во-вторых, значение `full_description` целиком никогда не совпадёт со строкой из $text, потому что там ещё есть какие-то цифры и загадочное слово "текст". Правильный запрос я добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно сказать точно, не имея возможности взглянуть на индексируемые данные, но я попробую угадать проблему. Скорее всего дело в том, что Иванцова зовут Иван, а Иванова - нет. Параметр `fuzziness`, равный в запросе двум, позволяет считать слова "Иванов" и "Иван" нечётким совпадением. В результате Иванцов Иван считается двойным совпадением, в то время как Иванов, имеющий менее банальное имя, считается одинарным.

По крайней мере, у меня аналогичный результат получается лишь при таких данных.

```
POST index1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": "russian"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "updated": { "type": "date" },
        "full_description": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST index1/person
{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2015-04-22T19:00:00",
  "full_description": "Иванов Петр"
}

POST index1/person
{
  "id": 2,
  "date": "2015-04-22T19:00:00",
  "full_description": "Иванцов Иван"
}

GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_description": {
        "query": "Иванов",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000000
}
```

Видимо, нужно либо уменьшить нечёткость, либо Иванцову поменять имя.

---

**Дополнение, сделанное после того, как ситуация прояснилась.**

Для того, чтобы принудительно поднять наверх результаты, найденные по точному совпадению, нужно использовать запрос `function_score`.

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "full_description": {
            "query": "Иванов",
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "prefix_length": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "full_description": "иванов"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1000
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

То, что слово в фильтре написано в нижнем регистре, не случайно. Это важно, поскольку в таком контексте ожидается строка, которая уже `analyzed`. Никаких дополнительных преобразований с ней происходить не будет. Она будет тупо сопоставляться с `analyzed`-полем из индекса.

Comment: Все заработало :) огромное Спасибо.

Comment: еще один такой вопрос, регулярку не могу сделать для слова, например ввести Рабино, что бы стал Рабинович. Делаю рабино."*\s" и не работает в regexp. \s вроде пробел, а * много символов

Comment: @PadreRv Это уже совершенно другой вопрос. Его нужно задавать отдельно и оформлять более развёрнуто.

Comment: Все, разобрался, заработало так "full_description"=>$textArr[0]."(.)+" Странно что символы ? * \s не поддерживает, а пробел определяет автоматом

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один вопрос: С запросом Иванов Л.А. так не работает, странно что не сравнивает всю фразу, потому я сделал разбивку запроса на слова, потом методом научного тыка увидел что фильтры умножаются, что очень даже хорошо, потому почти окончательный вариант у меня вышел такой:

```
$textArr = explode(" ", mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8')); //делаю масив из слов
```

тут запрос заготовка

```
$request = array(
    "from" => 0,
    "size"=>1000000,
      "query"=> array(
        "function_score"=> array(
          "query"=> array(
            "match"=> array(
              "full_description"=> array(
                "query"=> $text,
                "fuzziness"=> 2,
                "prefix_length"=> 1
              )
            )
          ),
          "functions"=> array(
            ),
            "boost_mode"=> "multiply"
        )
      )
    );
```

тут добавляю фильтры, первое слово с weight = 1000, второе 500 и так далее

```
    for($i=0; $i < count($textArr); $i++){
        $request["query"]["function_score"]["functions"][$i] = array(
                    "filter"=>array(
                        "term"=>array(
                            "full_description"=>$textArr[$i]
                        )
                    ),
                    "weight"=> 1000/($i+1)
                );
    }
```

тут делаю похожее первое слово с weight=500

```
    $request["query"]["function_score"]["functions"][count($textArr)] = array(
                    "filter"=>array(
                        "regexp"=>array(
                            "full_description"=>$textArr[0]."."
                        )
                    ),
                    "weight"=> 500
                );
```

Думаю сделать ранги в зависимости от длинны слова и похожее, что последнее взять самое длинное слово. Пересмотрел фильтры что сдесь http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html, ничего стандартного не нашел, с "type":  "phrase" тоже ничего не получилось. Может регулярным выражением можно заменить, это очень даже хорошо что они поддерживаются. Еще раз спасибо за решение.