# нечеткий поиск в ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, нечеткий-поиск

Здравствуйте, запрос взят из предыдущего вашего ответа. 
[Неправильная оценка при поиске fuzziness в elasticsearch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418469/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-fuzziness-%D0%B2-elasticsearch#new-answer?newreg=672523a8fd6a4e42b57c3f0e2c4558e2)
Бьюсь с похожей историей, ищет вроде-бы не плохо, но вот при запросе "женские платья", сначала находит "женские спортивные платья", потом "женский платок" и затем "женские платья".

Ниже сам запрос и маппинг:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'keywords_index',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => '5',
            'number_of_replicas' => '1',
            'analysis' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'autocomplete_filter'=>[
                        'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                        'min_gram' =>  '1',
                        'max_gram' => '15'
                    ],
                    'russian_stop' => [
                        'type' => 'stop',
                        'stopwords' => '_russian_'
                     ],
                     'russian_stemmer' => [
                         'type' => 'stemmer',
                         'language' => 'russian'
                      ],
                     'my_synonyms' => [
                        'type' => 'synonym',
                        'synonyms' => [ 'купить => одежда' ]
                     ]
                ],
                'analyzer' => [
                  'a_analyzer' => [
                      'type' => 'custom',
                      'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                      'filter' => ['lowercase', 'autocomplete_filter']
                  ],
                  'f_analyzer' => [
                      'type' => 'custom',
                      'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                      'filter' => ['lowercase', 'russian_morphology', 'russian_stemmer', 'russian_stop', 'english_morphology']
                  ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            'my_type' => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                  'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                      'type' => 'float'
                    ],
                    'p1' => [
                      'type' => 'float'
                    ],
                    'p2' => [
                      'type' => 'float'
                    ],
                    'p3' => [
                      'type' => 'float'
                    ],
                    'name' => [
                      'type' => 'keyword',
                      'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ],
                    'keywords' => [
                      'type' => 'text',
                      'analyzer' => 'a_analyzer',
                      'search_analyzer' => 'f_analyzer'
                    ],
                    'key_filter' => [
                      'type' => 'text',
                      'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ],
                    'type_filtr' => [
                      'type' => 'float'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];



$request = array(
"from" => 0,
"size"=>5,
  "query"=> array(
    "function_score"=> array(
      "query"=> array(
        "match"=> array(
          "keywords"=> array(
            "query"=> "женские платья",
            "fuzziness"=> 2,
            "prefix_length"=> 1
          )
        )
      ),
      "functions"=> array(
        "filter" => [
          "term" => [
            "keywords" => "женские платья"
        ]
      ],
      "weight" => 500
        ),
        "boost_mode"=> "multiply"
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет необходимости в использовании function_score, т.к. дополнительный вес добавляется одним и тем же результатам выборки (что не меняет порядок выдачи).

Для того, чтобы поднять "женские платья" наверх, можно использовать match_phrase query. С параметром slop = 2 или 3. При этом "женский платок" пропадет из результатов, т.к. отсутствует ключ "платья".

```
"query"=> array(
    "match"=> array(
      "keywords"=> array(
        "query"=> "женские платья",
        "fuzziness"=> 2,
        "prefix_length"=> 1,
        "type"=>'phrase',
        "slop"=> 2
      )
    )
  )
```

Либо, если платки все-таки тоже нужны, просто в самом низу, то можно обернуть все bool-ом и добавить match_phrase в категорию SHOULD как фактор ранжирования со slop = 50.

Подробнее здесь - [Proximity fo Relevance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-relevance.html)